# backpack for laravel: how to customize routes?

Tags: laravel-backpack

We need to change every `<anything>/show` routes to something localized.

How can we customize the `show` string in something like `dettagli` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in two way:

1. By creating a custom operation, starting from the default Show operation. Copy-paste [the code of the ShowOperation.php](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/app/Http/Controllers/Operations/ShowOperation.php) in your project, and change the route. Then throughout your project use *your* ShowOperation, instead of the one provided by Backpack.
2. By overriding the `protected function setupShowRoutes($segment, $routeName, $controller)` in your CrudController. If you have that method in your `ProductCrudController` for example, your method will be run instead of the one in the `ShowOperation` trait. However, this needs to be done in all CrudControllers individually, so it's less DRY.